# Fastclick for touch devices with ZURB Foundation?

Tags: touch, zurb-foundation

If I create a responsive website using ZURB's **Foundation**, will I need to include a library like **Fastclick** (by FTLabs) in order to avoid the 300 ms click delay on touch devices?

Seems the library should include this since getting things to act nice on mobile is its main purpose.

I guess, when I think about it, it seems that **fastclick** should be included on every single website that needs to be displayed on a touch device - or not...?

Comment: The delay can also be avoided by disabling zoom with `user-scalable=no` – **except** on iOS. So it really should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the old accepted answer is not valid anymore. Fastclick is used by Foundation now.

Found this on Foundation Github repo when searching for "Fastclick" there:

[image: Result of Fastclick search in Foundation Github Repo]

(From https://github.com/zurb/foundation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fastclick)

Also, I found this on Foundation Github repo:

```
  // Enable FastClick if present
  $(function () {
    if (typeof FastClick !== 'undefined') {
      // Don't attach to body if undefined
      if (typeof document.body !== 'undefined') {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
      }
    }
  });
```

(Source from: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/d2c9a9a7e84e53e5eff41ac2f61a8425f0760086/js/foundation/foundation.js)

So, this basically means that you **can** use Fastclick if you want and Foundation will initialize it for you but you can also decide to exclude if from your libs and Fastclick will not be used.

Answer (score 4):

All of [Foundation's Javascript libraries are listed here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascripts.php).

- jquery.js
- jquery.foundation.alerts.js -     **Adds the ability to close alerts**
- jquery.foundation.buttons.js -    **Adds dropdown functionality for dropdown buttons and split**
- jquery.foundation.accordion.js -  **Add open/close functionality to accordions**
- jquery.foundation.navigation.js -  **Adds functionality to navigation elements**
- jquery.foundation.topbar.js -  **Adds functionality for the top bar**
- jquery.foundation.forms.js -  **Adds ability to create custom form elements**
- jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle.js -   **Adds helpful media query viewer tool**
- jquery.foundation.tabs.js -  **Adds toggle capability to tabs**
- jquery.foundation.tooltips.js -   **Adds tooltips functionality**
- jquery.placeholder.js -   **Adds placeholder functions to forms**
- jquery.foundation.orbit.js -  **Our custom image/content slider plugin**
- jquery.foundation.reveal.js -     **Our simple modal plugin**
- jquery.foundation.clearing.js -   **Our new image gallery plugin**
- jquery.foundation.magellan.js -   **Our sweet new sticky nav plugin.**
- jquery.foundation.joyride.js -    **An awesome feature tour plugin.**

None of them covers [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)'s functionality, so the anwer is **if you wish to avoid the 300ms click delay, then add Fastclick manually**. About if it "should be included in every single website that is displayed on a touch device", I believe it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: This seems not be valid anymore, Fastclick is actually used in Foundation: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fastclick

Answer (score 0):

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html
The Doc says use it, I am not sure what would be the problem without it tho